# How can the port numbers of all active reverse SSH connections be listed?

Tags: networking, ssh, port, localhost

I have multiple machines connecting to a single server by reverse SSH tunnels. So, each machine is running a command like the following:

```
while true; do
    ssh -X -R 19999:localhost:22 www.sern.pro
    sleep 30
done
```

The `19999` here would be varied for the different connections (e.g. `19990`, `19991` etc.). These reverse SSH connections could be accessed from the server using a command like the following:

```
ssh -X localhost -p 19999
```

How can the server display a list of active reverse SSH connections? I have attempted using `netstat` but this requires foreknowledge of the local ports in use and doesn't make it clear that it is a reverse SSH connection:

```
# netstat --all --timers | grep "19999"
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:19999 *:*                     LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:19999     [::]:*                  LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

Following a suggestion from @frank-thomas, I tried using the command `netstat --all --timers --program --numeric | grep ssh` to seek out non-standard SSH processes. When I do this, after the `netstat` TCP listings, I get UNIX listings like the following:

```
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name         Path
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    64179539 28569/sshd: username [pr P475
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     60024486 14205/sshd: username [pr P60024485
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     62232808 5088/sshd: username [pri P62232133
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    60024422 14205/sshd: username [pr P475
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     64180927 28569/sshd: username [pr P64180926
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8303     3911/sshd                P8304
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     60024487 14205/sshd: username [pr P60024488
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    62232598 5088/sshd: username [pri P475
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     64180931 28569/sshd: username [pr P64180932
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     62232798 5088/sshd: username [pri P62232797
```

How can this data be interpreted to give a listing of the reverse SSH tunnel ports in use on the server? How could a number like 19999 be derived from this?

Comment: would just ssh connections work? I believe you could add `-p` to netstat, and grep for `/ssh`. then any connection not on 22 is likely a reverse tunnel.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks very much for the suggestion. I've tried using `netstat` in a way like that which you suggest and I've edited my question to provide details on this. I am getting a listing of what may be the reverse SSH tunnels, but I'm not sure how to derive the ports in use from this listing. Would you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using:

netstat -anp | egrep '127.0.0.1:*(LISTEN|.*)' | sort

This command lists all the connections with the ports that are actives and sort it.

If you have a range of ports that only  includes, for example, a ports from 40000 to 45000 you can add the 4 to the egrep like '127.0.0.1:4*(LISTEN|.*)' to get only that ones that starts with 4 instead of getting all the ports.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
sudo ss -ltp | grep sshd
```

to list all TCP ports opened for listening by an `sshd` process, including the default listener (typically on `tcp/22`, but elsewhere if you have chosen to configure an alternate port for the `sshd` daemon).  You could then examine the listed PIDs to determine what user had opened the `ssh` connection which was listening on each port.